# How to display commenter image using php codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I want to display commenter's profile image inline with their comments in a comment system using Codeigniter.
I queried the blogcomment table:

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('blogcomment');
 $this->db->Order_by('date','desc');
 $data['getComment'] = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

I present it on the view:

```
<?php foreach ($getComment as $value):?>
      <div class="media mb-4">
          <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="<?php echo base_url('users_pic/'.$userP)?>" width="50px" height="50px" alt="">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h5 class="mt-0"><?php echo $value['userfn']?></h5>
          <?php echo $value['comment'] ?>
        </div>
          <div><button id="reply" class="btn btn-primary btn-small btn-
      block">Reply</button></div>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach;?>
```

I queried the image table:

```
 $getPic = $this->db->get("user_pictures")->result();
 foreach ($getPic as $userPic){
 $data['userid'] = $userPic->uniq_userid;
 $data['userP'] = $userPic->picture_name;

 }
```

The above codes displays the session image, that is the logged in user's image not the commenter's image.
 I have done this using Java with the following code:

```
 <div id="pic"><%out.println("<img width = 36 height = 40 src=freepicview.jsp?
 UserId=" + rss.getString("UserId") + "></img>");%></div>
```

So I tried it with PHP but no luck:

```
<?php echo (" <img src=userpic.php?userid"= $value['bcuniq_userid']" width=50 height=50></img>");?>
```

I tried this no luck:

```
 <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="<?php echo 
 base_url('users_pic/'.$userP.$userid ='bcuniq_userid')?>" width="50px" 
 height="50px" alt="">
```

Blogcomment Table:
      `blogcomment`
      --

```
   CREATE TABLE `blogcomment` (
   `bcid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `bcuniq_userid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `userfn` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `userln` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `blog_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `comment` text NOT NULL,
    `date` varchar(25) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

User Pics Table:

### `user_pictures`

```
   CREATE TABLE `user_pictures` (
   `picid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `picture_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `uniq_userid` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
   `date` varchar(30) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried other ways no luck still. Please help me on how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: can you give me detail of "user_pictures" and "blogcomment" table, joining this two table you get picture of commentator.

Comment: @NimishaMolia  I have updated the question with the table details. I will also try the join.

Comment: `$this->db->select('b.*,u.picture_name');
 $this->db->from('blogcomment as b');
$this->db->join('user_pictures as u','u.uniq_userid=b.bcuniq_userid');
 $this->db->Order_by('b.date','desc');
 $data['getComment'] = $this->db->get()->result_array();`

after that

`<img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="PATH TO FOLDER. $value['picture_name']" width="50px" height="50px" alt="">
     `

Comment: @NimishaMolia  It worked. Thank you